How to install GApps/Magisk any addon through the TWRP recovery to the Android Virtual Device based on Android 5.1.1 and the Nexus 10
I'm trying to install GApps/Magisk etc any addon through the TWRP recovery to the Android Virtual Device based on Android 5.1.1 and the Nexus 10. The first step that I have accomplished has been to boot the TWRP thanks to an hint found here :
https://github.com/TeamWin/android_device_emulator_twrp/issues/2
He suggested to use an older version of SDK Tools(24.4.1). With it I have booted TWRP 2.8.0.1 in android 5.1.1 armeabi-v7a for the tablet Nexus 10 :
$ /home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/tools_r24.4.1/./emulator -verbose -avd Nexus_10_API_22 -
ramdisk /home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/twrp-2.8.0.1-twrp.img -kernel /home/ziomario/
Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/goldfish_3.4_kernel -show-kernel -gpu off

emulator:Found AVD name 'Nexus_10_API_22'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: arm
emulator:Looking for emulator-arm to emulate 'arm' CPU
emulator:Probing program: /home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/tools_r24.4.1/./emulator64-arm
emulator:return result: /home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/tools_r24.4.1/./emulator64-arm
emulator:Found target-specific emulator binary: /home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/tools_r24.4.1/./emulator64-arm
emulator:GPU emulation is disabled
emulator: Running :/home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/tools_r24.4.1/./emulator64-arm
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "/home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/tools_r24.4.1/./emulator64-arm"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-verbose"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "-avd"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[03] = "Nexus_10_API_22"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[04] = "-ramdisk"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[05] = "/home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/twrp-2.8.0.1-twrp.img"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[06] = "-kernel"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[07] = "/home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/goldfish_3.4_kernel"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[08] = "-show-kernel"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[09] = "-gpu"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[10] = "off"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/tools_r24.4.1/./emulator64-arm -verbose -avd Nexus_10_API_22 -ramdisk /home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/twrp-2.8.0.1-twrp.img -kernel /home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/goldfish_3.4_kernel -show-kernel -gpu off
emulator: found ANDROID_SDK_ROOT: /home/ziomario/Android/Sdk/
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 22
emulator: Read property file at /home/ziomario/Android/Sdk//system-images/android-22/google_apis/armeabi-v7a//build.prop
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: found skin 'nexus_10' in directory: /home/ziomario/Android/Sdk/skins
emulator: autoconfig: -skin nexus_10
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /home/ziomario/Android/Sdk/skins
emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/ziomario/.android/default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file '/home/ziomario/Android/Sdk/skins/nexus_10/layout'
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires legacy device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: Using initial system image: /home/ziomario/Android/Sdk//system-images/android-22/google_apis/armeabi-v7a//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1907MB

emulator: GPU emulation is disabled
emulator: WARNING: CPU acceleration only works with x86/x86_64 system images.
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
  hw.ramSize = 1907
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = no
  hw.trackBall = no
  hw.keyboard = yes
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = no
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  hw.sdCard.path = /home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 1600
  hw.lcd.height = 2560
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 320
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.initialOrientation = landscape
  hw.camera.back = none
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 192
  hw.sensors.proximity = no
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  hw.useext4 = yes
  kernel.path = /home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/goldfish_3.4_kernel
  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = no
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
  disk.ramdisk.path = /home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/twrp-2.8.0.1-twrp.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /home/ziomario/Android/Sdk//system-images/android-22/google_apis/armeabi-v7a//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 1500m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 2g
  avd.name = Nexus_10_API_22
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/tools_r24.4.1/./emulator64-arm"
emulator: argv[01] = "-show-kernel"
emulator: argv[02] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[03] = "/home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/tools_r24.4.1/./emulator64-arm -show-kernel -android-hw /home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
failed to load image file '/home/ziomario/Android/Sdk/skins/nexus_10//port_back.webp'
emulator: ## WARNING: can't load part '<NULL>' from skin

failed to load image file '/home/ziomario/Android/Sdk/skins/nexus_10//land_back.webp'
emulator: ## WARNING: can't load part '<NULL>' from skin

emulator: ### WARNING: ignoring part location with unknown name 'portrait'
emulator: ### WARNING: ignoring part location with unknown name 'landscape'
emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator:     trying to find: /home/ziomario/Scrivania/FILES/watch?v=LL4lLoMCvMY/tools_r24.4.1/lib/ca-bundle.pem

emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Using kernel serial device prefix: ttyS
emulator: Ramdisk image contains fstab.goldfish file
emulator: Found format of system partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of userdata partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of cache partition: 'ext4'
emulator: system partition format: ext4
emulator: Mapping 'system' partition image to /tmp/android-ziomario/emulator-s31jL5
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x5dc00000,file=/tmp/android-ziomario/emulator-s31jL5,initfile=/home/ziomario/Android/Sdk//system-images/android-22/google_apis/armeabi-v7a//system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: userdata partition format: ext4
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x80000000,file=/home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd/userdata-qemu.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: cache partition format: ext4
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/home/ziomario/.android/avd/Nexus_10_API_22.avd/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '192m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '320'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator: autoconfig: -scale 0.471507
serial0 console
emulator: Forcing ro.adb.qemud to "0".
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized

emulator: Failed to parse .AndroidStudio preferences file usage.statistics.xml
emulator: Defaulting user crash-report opt-in to false
emulator: Skipping metrics reporting: No user opt-in.
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
goldfish_fb_get_pixel_format:170: display surface,pixel format:
  bits/pixel:  16
  bytes/pixel: 2
  depth:       16
  red:         bits=5 mask=0xf800 shift=11 max=0x1f
  green:       bits=6 mask=0x7e0 shift=5 max=0x3f
  blue:        bits=5 mask=0x1f shift=0 max=0x1f
  alpha:       bits=0 mask=0x0 shift=0 max=0x0
Booting Linux on physical CPU 0
Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Linux version 3.4.67-gd3ffcc7 (dees_troy@XPS12-Ubuntu) (gcc version 4.6.x-google 20120106 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #2 PREEMPT Thu Aug 14 16:20:36 CDT 2014
CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc080] revision 0 (ARMv7), cr=10c53c7d
CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT nonaliasing instruction cache
Machine: Goldfish
Truncating RAM at 00000000-772fffff to -2f7fffff (vmalloc region overlap).
Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 193040
Kernel command line: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
Memory: 760MB = 760MB total
Memory: 745824k/745824k available, 32416k reserved, 0K highmem
Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xfff00000 - 0xfffe0000   ( 896 kB)
    vmalloc : 0xf0000000 - 0xff000000   ( 240 MB)
    lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xef800000   ( 760 MB)
      .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc0454578   (4402 kB)
      .init : 0xc0455000 - 0xc047a000   ( 148 kB)
      .data : 0xc047a000 - 0xc04b3808   ( 231 kB)
       .bss : 0xc04b382c - 0xc05fdaf0   (1321 kB)
NR_IRQS:256
sched_clock: 32 bits at 100 Hz, resolution 10000000ns, wraps every 4294967286ms
Console: colour dummy device 80x30
Calibrating delay loop... 1047.75 BogoMIPS (lpj=5238784)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Security Framework initialized
SELinux:  Initializing.
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
Initializing cgroup subsys debug
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
Setting up static identity map for 0x368698 - 0x3686f0
NET: Registered protocol family 16
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
Switching to clocksource goldfish_timer
NET: Registered protocol family 2
IP route cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
TCP established hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 131072 bind 65536)
TCP: reno registered
UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
NET: Registered protocol family 1
RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
Freeing initrd memory: 2976K
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_interrupt_controller at ff000000 irq -1
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_device_bus at ff001000 irq 1
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_timer at ff003000 irq 3
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_rtc at ff010000 irq 10
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_tty at ff002000 irq 4
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_tty at ff011000 irq 11
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_tty at ff012000 irq 12
goldfish_new_pdev smc91x at ff013000 irq 13
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_fb at ff014000 irq 14
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_audio at ff004000 irq 15
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_mmc at ff005000 irq 16
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish-battery at ff015000 irq 17
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_events at ff016000 irq 18
goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_nand at ff017000 irq -1
goldfish_new_pdev qemu_pipe at ff018000 irq 19
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_interrupt_controller
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_device_bus
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_timer
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_rtc
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_tty
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_tty
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_tty
goldfish_pdev_worker registered smc91x
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_fb
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_audio
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_mmc
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish-battery
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_events
goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_nand
goldfish_pdev_worker registered qemu_pipe
audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
type=2000 audit(0.350:1): initialized
Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
fuse init (API version 7.18)
msgmni has been set to 1462
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
console [ttyS0] enabled
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
nbd: registered device at major 43
goldfish_audio_probe
goldfish nand dev0: size 5dc00000, page 512, extra 0, erase 0
goldfish nand dev1: size 80000000, page 512, extra 0, erase 0
goldfish nand dev2: size 4200000, page 512, extra 0, erase 0
tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
smc91x.c: v1.1, sep 22 2004 by Nicolas Pitre <nico@fluxnic.net>
eth0: SMC91C11xFD (rev 1) at fe013000 IRQ 13 [nowait]
eth0: Ethernet addr: 52:54:00:12:34:56
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
*** events probe ***
events_probe() addr=0xfe016000 irq=18
events_probe() keymap=qwerty2
input: qwerty2 as /devices/virtual/input/input0
goldfish_rtc goldfish_rtc: rtc core: registered goldfish_rtc as rtc0
device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
ashmem: initialized
logger: created 256K log 'log_main'
logger: created 256K log 'log_events'
logger: created 256K log 'log_radio'
logger: created 256K log 'log_system'
Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (11700 buckets, 46800 max)
ctnetlink v0.93: registering with nfnetlink.
NF_TPROXY: Transparent proxy support initialized, version 4.1.0
NF_TPROXY: Copyright (c) 2006-2007 BalaBit IT Ltd.
xt_time: kernel timezone is -0000
ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
arp_tables: (C) 2002 David S. Miller
TCP: cubic registered
NET: Registered protocol family 10
ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
NET: Registered protocol family 17
NET: Registered protocol family 15
8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant c rev 0
goldfish_rtc goldfish_rtc: setting system clock to 2024-08-21 19:34:03 UTC (1724268843)
Freeing init memory: 148K
mmc0: new SD card at address e118
mmcblk0: mmc0:e118 SU02G 512 MiB 
 mmcblk0:
type=1403 audit(1724268843.570:2): policy loaded auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
SELinux: Loaded policy from /sepolicy
type=1404 audit(1724268843.580:3): enforcing=1 old_enforcing=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
init: /dev/hw_random not found
init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
eth0: link up
init: /dev/hw_random not found
init: Unable to open persistent property directory /data/property errno: 2
init: using deprecated syntax for specifying property 'ro.serialno', use ${name} instead
init: property 'ro.serialno' doesn't exist while expanding '$ro.serialno'
init: cannot expand '$ro.serialno' while writing to '/sys/class/android_usb/android0/iSerial'
EXT4-fs (mtdblock1): recovery complete
EXT4-fs (mtdblock1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
EXT4-fs (mtdblock0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:


Now,let's say I want to install Magisk using the TWRP to the emulator, what should I do ? I imagine that I should save the Magisk file (or any other zipped adddon) inside the sd card...or ? How can I do this ?
